# jQuery multiple select checkboxes if specific is checked

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to select multiple checkboxes inside a div, if a specific checkbox is selected. Here's what I'm trying to do http://jsfiddle.net/8PLH6/

I'm trying to make this work. If I check "All" all the below checkboxes should be selected. For some reason I can't get the selectors right.
Code:

```
<div style="float:left;padding-right:15px;">
<div align="left" style="padding-bottom: 4px; padding-left: 6px;" class="bottom">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="all"/><a href="#" title="All">All</a>
</div>
<div align="left" style="padding-bottom: 4px; padding-left: 6px;" class="bottom">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="cat417"/><a href="" title="1">1</a>
</div>
<div align="left" style="padding-bottom: 4px; padding-left: 6px;" class="bottom">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="cat410"/><a href="" title="2">2</a>
</div>
<div align="left" style="padding-bottom: 4px; padding-left: 6px;" class="bottom">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="cat401"/><a href="" title="3">3</a>
</div>
<div align="left" style="padding-bottom: 4px; padding-left: 6px;" class="bottom">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="cat415"/><a href="" title="4">4</a>
</div>
</div>
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#all').change(function () {
    $a = $(this).parent('div').parent('div').children('div').children('input[type="checkbox"]');
    $b = $(this).attr('checked');
    if ($b) {
        $($a).attr('checked', true);
    } else {
        $($a).attr('checked', false);
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be very tricky. Please use the `.prop()` function.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#all').on("click",function () {
          $("input[type='checkbox']").not("#all").each(function() 
       {
           $(this).prop("checked",$("#all").is(":checked"));
        });
    });
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8PLH6/3/

Comment: @Haniet Thanks - that's exactly what I wanted. However if I have another div with checkboxes, they become selected, too. I wish I could prevent that. See what I mean http://jsfiddle.net/8PLH6/4/